# EasyMapping do not map CoreData one to many relationship objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I use EasyMapping library for object unmarshalling from JSON to my
CoreData objects. Object Balance has to-many relationship with Transaction, this is my nsmanaggedobject class:

```
class Balance: NSManagedObject, EKManagedMappingProtocol {

static func objectMapping() -> EKManagedObjectMapping! {
    return EKManagedObjectMapping.init(forEntityName: String(self), withBlock: { (mapping) -> Void in

        mapping.mapKeyPath("balance.amount", toProperty: "amount")

        mapping.hasMany(Transaction.self, forKeyPath: "transactions")
    })
}

}
```

this is my translation bit:

```
        let b = Balance.MR_createEntityInContext(localContext)

        EKMapper.fillObject(b, fromExternalRepresentation: parsedInfo, withMapping: Balance.objectMapping())
```

my entity is created fine, but no relationships.
Would appreciate any ideas on why is that not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution, you need to inherit entity class from EKManagedObjectModel like the following

```
class Balance: EKManagedObjectModel {

static func objectMapping() -> EKManagedObjectMapping! {
return EKManagedObjectMapping.init(forEntityName: String(self), withBlock: { (mapping) -> Void in

    mapping.mapKeyPath("balance.amount", toProperty: "amount")

    mapping.hasMany(Transaction.self, forKeyPath: "transactions")
    })
  }
}
```

and translation would be

```
        MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({ (localContext) -> Void in

        let b = Balance.objectWithProperties(parsedPersonInfo, inContext: localContext)
 ...
}
```